# insert specific element inside eod

Tags: php, heredoc

I need to inject a code inside a file when there is an intallation

the result must be

```
if (isset($_SESSION['admin']['id'])) {
  define('DIR_FS_IMAGES', '{$dir_fs_document_root}images/');  
  define('DIR_WS_IMAGES', '{$http_catalog}images/'); 
}
```

Inside the process install I tried this but if do not seems work well.
How to process to have the same result above ?

Thank you

```
$file_contents = <<<ENDCFG
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['admin']['id'])) {
define('DIR_FS_IMAGES', '{$dir_fs_document_root}/images/');  // path to files (REQUIRED)
define('DIR_WS_IMAGES', '{$http_catalog}/images/'); // URL to files (REQUIRED)
}
ENDCFG;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to escape dollar sign character `$` in heredoc string, or use [nowdoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) string instead

> Nowdocs are to single-quoted strings what heredocs are to double-quoted strings. A nowdoc is specified similarly to a heredoc, but no parsing is done inside a nowdoc.

```
<?php
$file_contents = <<<'ENDCFG'
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['admin']['id'])) {
define('DIR_FS_IMAGES', '{$dir_fs_document_root}/images/');  // path to files (REQUIRED)
define('DIR_WS_IMAGES', '{$http_catalog}/images/'); // URL to files (REQUIRED)
}
ENDCFG;

file_put_contents('/tmp/out.php', $file_contents);
```

Result

```
$ php test.php
$ file out.php
out.php: PHP script text, ASCII text
$ cat out.php
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['admin']['id'])) {
define('DIR_FS_IMAGES', '{$dir_fs_document_root}/images/');  // path to files (REQUIRED)
define('DIR_WS_IMAGES', '{$http_catalog}/images/'); // URL to files (REQUIRED)
}
```